# Prove 1 + 4 Product of fibonacci numbers is a perfect square

Tags: number-theory, fibonacci-numbers

Let $n  \in \mathbb N$ . Prove that

$1 + 4 F_{2n}F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2}F_{2n+3}$ is the square of an integer.

I first tried to used Cassini's identities but failed.I tried then by induction and again failed.

$P(1) = 1 + 4F_2 F_3 F_4 F_5 = 121 = 11^2 $

Assuming $P(k)$ to be true and equal to $I^2$

$P(k+1) = 1 + (I^2 - 1) \frac{F_{2n + 4}F_{2n+5}}{F_{2n}F_{2n+1}}$ but how to proceed from here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the [fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cassini_and_Catalan_identities) that $F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2} - F_{2n}F_{2n+3}= 1$, you can write this as:
$$1+4F_{2n}F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2}F_{2n+3} = 1+4F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2}(F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2}-1)$$ Let $x = F_{2n+1}F_{2n+2}$ and this expression becomes:
$$1+4x(x-1) = 4x^2-4x+1 = (2x-1)^2$$

Comment: could I prove it by just using Cassini's identities? I was just told that.

Comment: @VisheshMangla You can prove that $F_{n}F_{n+1}-F_{n-1}F_{n+2} = (-1)^n$ using Cassini's identity: $F_{n}F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}F_{n+2} = F_{n}F_{n+1} - F_{n-1}(F_{n}+F_{n+1}) = F_{n}^2-F_{n}^2 + (-1)^n = (-1)^n$.

Comment: Thank you @Tan .